# Appending button onclick function runs when appended

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

When I append a button with an onclick function, that same functions runs immediately. How do I keep the onclick function and make it not run when appended? Heres the code where it gets appended:

```
let button=document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML=users[i].replace("user__","").replace("=","").substring(0,users[i].replace("user__","").replace("=","").length/2);
button.onclick=removeUser(button.innerHTML);
accounts.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your codebase, the `button.onclick` needs to be asigned as a function.

But in the code it is `button.onclick=removeUser(button.innerHTML)`, due to this line `removeUser` would be directly executed when creating the button.

You might have to update your code as follow:

```js
button.onclick = () => removeUser(button.innerHTML)
```

This way, the `removeUser` is wrapped inside a function and that function is only called when user clicks on the button. Hope this helps. :)